# What do we call the proper set inclusion with no boundary intersections?

Tags: general-topology

Let ${\mathcal A}$ and ${\mathcal B}$ be two compact sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$. If ${\mathcal A} \subset {\mathcal B}$ with ${\mathcal A} \bigcap \partial {\mathcal B} = \emptyset$ (where $\partial {\mathcal B}$ stands for the boundary of ${\mathcal B}$), is there any name for such a relation? Any notation for it? Thanks!

Comment: This condition is equivalent to $\mathcal{A} \subseteq \mathcal{B}^{\circ}$, where $\mathcal{B}^{\circ}$ denotes the interior of $\mathcal{B}$.

Comment: There is no notion of "boundary" unless a topology is defined.  It is possible that you have in mind that $A$ is contained in the *interior* of  $B$.

Comment: @CliveNewstead Thanks very much for your answer :-)

Comment: @hardmath Thanks a lot :-) Since $\mathcal{B}$ is compact in $\mathbb{R}^n$, the closure is itself. We can define the boundary correspondingly in $\mathbb{R}^n$. But you are right, the notion of "boundary" relies on how the topology is defined in general. Thanks again :-)

Comment: You could say that "A is compactly contained in the interior of B", written $A \Subset B^\circ$.

Comment: @PhoemueX Thank you so much :-)